# Making a discord Ticket System on DM with python

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a ticket system on DM with python. For now I've done this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    reaction = await bot.add_reaction(emoji="1️⃣" and "2️⃣", message=message)
    embedP = discord.Embed(title="Benvenuto nel ticket!", description="""Come possiamo aiutarti?
                          
                          1️⃣ Reportare una persona
                          2️⃣ Domanda ad un admin""", colour=discord.Colour.red())
    if bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedP)
        if reaction.emoji == "1️⃣":
            return
```

I know it's incomplete.

I want that when you click the 1️⃣ or 2️⃣ emoji the person have to write a description of the problem that he is experiencing and for the bot to send it to a specific chat on my server and by pinging the bot the admin can reply to the message and the person can respond by placing a randomly generated code in square brackets.

I need to make the emoji system too, so can someone help me?

I tried to make the emoji system but it won't work